# Existence of nice Folner sequences

Tags: amenability, gr.group-theory

I'm attempting a proof by induction and, for the inductive step, it would be very useful for me to have some control on a Folner sequence. Indeed, let $G$ be a finitely generated amenable group, fix a finite symmetric set of generators for $G$ and denote by $B_n$ the ball of radius $n$ in the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect of the fixed generators.

Is it possible to find a Folner sequence $(F_n:n\in\mathbb N)$ for $G$ satisfying the following properties?

(1) $F_1\subseteq F_2\subseteq F_3\subseteq \dots$ and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n=G$;

(2) for all $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists $k$ such that $B_k\subseteq F_n\subseteq B_{k+1}$.

Comment: It will work if your group has subexponential growth. 

Comment: @Misha: well... in that case ${B_n:n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Folner sequence so the interesting case is when you have exponential growth...


Comment: @Simone: It may happen that your condition is satisfied only for groups of subexponential  growth. I cannot think of a group of exponential growth for which the condition is true. 

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for your answer and comment! 
I'm trying to understand how some dynamical results in dynamical systems of the form $G\times M\to M$ (with $G$ amenable and $M$ an Abelian discrete group) generalize from the case when $G$ is Abelian (e.g. $\mathbb Z^n$) to the general situation. I admit that my intuition is still not that good in the non-commutative case!

Comment: @Simone: Folner sets usually have complicated shapes. It was noticed right after the original paper by Folner. I do not remember the references but it (the references) must be in the standard books on amenability (Greenleaf or Wagon).

Comment: What you ask is a bit demanding and might be sensitive on the choice of generating set. On the other hand, Romain Tessera has proved that many groups have such a sequence $(F_n)$ with $B_{cn}\subset F_n\subset B_{Cn}$ for constants $c<C$. These include polycyclic groups and lamplighters over finite groups, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603138. (The condition $\bigcup F_n=G$ is not hard to require but is usually useless... for instance the Følner sets $[-n,n]$ or $[0,2n]$ in $\mathbf{Z}$ behave the same way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible for $\mathbb{Z}\wr \mathbb{Z}$ and (most) other groups. For the structure of Folner sets there, see, in particular, Erschler, Anna 
On isoperimetric profiles of finitely generated groups. (English summary) 
Geom. Dedicata 100 (2003), 157–171.  and references there.